# EMI jee metallic rod rotating in uniform perpendicular magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, rotational-dynamics, centripetal-force

A metallic rod is rotating about a vertical axis through its end. For finding the EMF $E$ between the ends we simply equate $m\omega^2r=Eq$ then find $\sqrt{-Edr}$. So for this calculation we consider centripetal force.

But when a uniform perpendicular magnetic field $B$ (parallel to axis) is switched on, due to the Lorentz force a redistribution of charge takes place and to calculate it we equate $Eq=qvB$ at static condition. So the EMF is $\tfrac12 B\omega l^2$.

But why we didn't consider centripetal concept here? I mean we should do something like $m\omega^2r=Eq-qvb$.

Please explain from basics. I am totally confused.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" questions.

Comment: This is clearly a question about concepts.

Comment: But what has 'jee' (in the title) got to do with the question?

Comment: JEE is the name of an entrance exam, it's a big deal in India since it's the most valued criteria for admission into colleges, and hence, a good life (securities aren't the greatest). @PhilipWood

Comment: Thank you. I knew what 'JEE' meant, but wondered why you had put it in the title to your question. Its inclusion in the title may have suggested to some readers that you were asking for help with homework.

Answer (score 1):

You are using $E$ to stand for both magnitude of electric field strength and emf. Using $\mathscr E$ for emf, your 'rotational emf' in a rod of length $l$ is the 'work integral':
$$\mathscr E =\int_0^l \frac{m\omega^2r}{q} dr=\frac{m\omega^2}{q}\int_0^l  r dr =\frac{m\omega^2 l^2}{2q}$$
Putting in the mass and charge of an electron for $m$ and $q$, I find that for a 20 cm rod whirled at 50 revolutions per second about one end, $\mathscr E \approx 10$ nV. Perhaps that's why we usually ignore it!

May I suggest that you calculate the 'magnetic emf', $\mathscr E=\tfrac 12 B \omega l^2$, for the same rod, whirled at the same rate, in a modest magnetic field (say of 0.050 T)? You'll see what I mean!